# How can I extract pdf names from an lftp log file?

Tags: grep, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a log like this :

```
2016-05-11 07:09:54 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/1999/How/05%20May/test160511.pdf -> /test/keep/more/use/05/test160511.pdf 0-28442281 33.5 KiB/s
```

i need to extract only "test160511.pdf" and put in separate log file.

It is possible?

Comment: btw, if you prefer a script form, so you can run `<command> <logfile> <outputfile>`, just mention. I made it a one-liner because most people prefer it her :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a python one-liner:

```
python3 -c '[print(p+".pdf") for p in [s.split(".pdf")[0] for s in open("logfile").read().split("/") if ".pdf" in s]]'
```

where `"logfile"` is the path to your log file, between double quotes. An example, using the input of your question, where `/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pd.txt` is my log file:

```
$ python3 -c '[print(p+".pdf") for p in [s.split(".pdf")[0] for s in open("/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pd.txt").read().split("/") if "pdf" in s]]'
test160511.pdf
test160511.pdf
```

#### Explanation

The command:

- splits the content of the file by the dellimeter `/` (slash):

  ```
  open("logfile").read().split("/")
  ```

  and looks up the sections containing `pdf`:

  ```
  for s in open("/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pd.txt").read().split("/") if "pdf" in s
  ```
- Subsequently, it *splits* the found strings by the dellimeter `.pdf`, and keeps the first section, which is the section between `/` and `pdf`.
- subsequently, the extension is added:

  ```
  print(p+".pdf")
  ```

This way, the file name of the pdf's is always retrieved correctly, even if the (pdf-) filename contains spaces.

#### Only unique filenames?

If you don't want to repeat filenames with multiple occurrences:

```
python3 -c '[print(p+".pdf") for p in set([s.split(".pdf")[0] for s in open("logfile").read().split("/") if "pdf" in s])]'
```

From the same example:

```
$ python3 -c '[print(p+".pdf") for p in set([s.split(".pdf")[0] for s in open("/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pd.txt").read().split("/") if "pdf" in s])]'
test160511.pdf
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '.*/\K[^\s]+(?=\s+->)'
```

**Example:**

```
$ grep -Po '.*/\K[^\s]+(?=\s+->)' <<<'2016-05-11 07:09:54 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/1999/How/05%20May/test160511.pdf -> /test/keep/more/use/05/test160511.pdf 0-28442281 33.5 KiB/s'
test160511.pdf
```

---

Or `sed`:

```
sed -r 's#.*/([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->.*#\1#'
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed -nr 's#.*/([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+->.*#\1#p' <<<'2016-05-11 07:09:54 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/1999/How/05%20May/test160511.pdf -> /test/keep/more/use/05/test160511.pdf 0-28442281 33.5 KiB/s'
test160511.pdf
```

---

You can save the output using output redirection operator `>`:

```
grep .... >/where/to/save.log
```

So in this case:

```
grep -Po '.*/\K[^\s]+(?=\s+->)' <<<'your_string' >output.log
```

You can use an intermediate variable too:

```
temp=$(grep -Po '.*/\K[^\s]+(?=\s+->)' <<<'your_string')
```

and then save:

```
echo "$temp" >output.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but in my lftpd log i have many many *pdf; So ... how do I tell him looking all pdf  and print only the names .pdf ? :) thanks

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Please be precise when asking question..edit your question and add a chunk of input and your desired output from that..

Comment: So here the log example : 2016-05-08 06:27:13 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/2016/search/05%20may/aa160508.pdf -> /test/data/keep/fool/05/aa160508.pdf 0-29120689 53.1 KiB/s
2016-05-08 06:27:13 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/2016/search/05%20may/cds160508.pdf -> /test/data/keep/fool/05/cds160508.pdf 0-29120689 53.1 KiB/s
2016-05-08 06:27:13 ftp://test@test.dyndns.info/test1/fool/2016/ends/05%20may/mpf60508.pdf -> /test/data/keep/ends/05/mpf160508.pdf 0-29120689 53.1 KiB/s
 Need only aa160508.pdf, cds160508.pdf, mpf160508.pdf

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Please add this to your question..

Answer (score 3):

Another `grep` solution (`file` contains the example from your question):

```
$ grep -oP '/\K[^/]+\.pdf' file
test160511.pdf
test160511.pdf
```

For unique names only:

```
$ grep -oP '/\K[^/]+\.pdf' file | sort -u
test160511.pdf
```

#### Explanation

- `-o` : print only the matched portion of the line.
- `-P` : use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)
- `/\K[^/]+\.pdf` : match a `/` and then discard it (that's what the `\K` does, this way the `/` is not included in the output). Then, match one or more non-`/` characters (`[^/]+`), followed by `.pdf`. The `.` means "any character" in regular expressions, so to match a literal `.`, you need to escape it: `\.`
- `sort -u` : only print unique lines.